# How do I setup a member roles for a Users schema using mongoose

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a user schema with members, admin, user, a guest. This is what thinking, but is it a conventional way of doing so? I'm having trouble finding a good resource for learning how to do this.

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  role: {
    type: [
      {
        type: String,
        enum: ["user", "admin"],
        default: ["user"]
      }
     ]
   },
   email: {
     type: String,
     required: true
   },
   password: {
     type: String,
     required: true
   },
   date: {
     type: Date,
     default: Date.now
   }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

What you would want to do is to start with the smallest set of the properties you would need which is shared among the 3 model types (guest, user, admin) and that would be your base schema.

Then using [**Mongoose descriminators**](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html) (mongoose schema inheritance) you would inherit from it and decorate with more properties you level model.

For example your `guest` might not have a `role` property since he is a guest. So you might want to start with a base model of `guest` and add on top of it other props needed for the user/admin.

Example:

```
var options = {discriminatorKey: 'type'};

var guestSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
  username: { type: string, default: 'guest_' + Date.now },
}, options);

var Guest = mongoose.model('Guest', guestSchema);

var User = Guest.discriminator('User',
  new mongoose.Schema({password: String}, options));

// Now you have Guest as base model and User with decorated 'password' field
```

You can read the [official documentation on this here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html)

There are also plenty of articles online on the subject.